# use jquery - "each" to adding values into many <a href's>

Tags: jquery, foreach, href, title

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="title-1"></a>

<br />
<br /> <a href="" id="title-2">2. Test</a>

<br />
<br /> <a href="" id="title-3">3. Test</a>

<br />
<br /> <a href="" id="title-4">4. Subsyndromale Angststörung</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
test.getArticles("Learning").then(function (articles) {
    $.each(["title"], function (index, value) {
        var article = articles.contentarticles[index],
            $el = $("#" + value);
        $el.html(article.title);

    });
```

i like to use this JQuery  -each method to add value for each title of  in my html. at the moment i have 4 href's with id. this function works staticly, just with name "title". how to make it dynamic????

Comment: Can you explain what you need a bit more? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO idea what you're trying to do but to use each I would say, why not read its documention a little bit ;) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

But seeing as the href's are blank i'll assume its these that you wanto to add to:

```
$('a').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('href','newlink.html');
});
```

Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you give them all a the same class, you could capture the action on the class.

Example:

```
<a href="" class="menuOption" id="option1">Option 1</a>
<a href="" class="menuOption" id="option2">Option 2</a>
<a href="" class="menuOption" id="option3">Option 3</a>
<a href="" class="menuOption" id="option4">Option 4</a>
```

Then the jQuery would look like this:

```
$(".menuOption").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        //do something
    }
});
```